# How to calculate the rotation angle of two constrained segments?

Tags: javascript, algorithm, math, trigonometry

I have two vectors, the Y-aligned is fixed whereby the X-aligned is allowed to rotate. These vectors are connected together through two fixed-length segments. Given the angle between the two vectors (82.74) and the length of all segments, how can I get the angle of the two jointed segments (24.62 and 22.61)?

[image]

What is given: the magnitude of the vectors, and the angle between the X-axis and OG:

```
var magOG = 3,
    magOE = 4,
    magGH = 3,
    magEH = 2,
    angleGamma = 90;
```

This is my starting point: `angleGamma = 90` - then, I will have following vectors:

```
var vOG = new vec2(-3,0),
    vOE = new vec2(0,-4);
```

From here on, I am trying to get `angleAlpha`and `angleBeta` for values of `angleGamma` less than 90 degrees.

**MAGNITUDE OF THE CONSTRAINED SEGMENTS:**

Segments HG and HE must meet following conditions:

```
/
|  OG*OG+ OE*OE = (HG + HE)*(HG + HE)
>
|  OG - HG = OE - HE
\
```

which will lead to following two solutions (as pointed out in the accepted answer - bilateration):

```
Solution 1:
========================================================
HG = 0.5*(-Math.sqrt(OG*OG + OE*OE) + OG - OE)
HE = 0.5*(-Math.sqrt(OG*OG + OE*OE) - OG + OE)

Solution 2:
========================================================
HG = 0.5*(Math.sqrt(OG*OG + OE*OE) + OG - OE)
HE = 0.5*(Math.sqrt(OG*OG + OE*OE) - OG + OE)
```

---

**SCRATCHPAD:**

Here is a playground with the complete solution. The visualization library used here is the great [JSXGraph](https://jsxgraph.uni-bayreuth.de/wp/index.html). Thanks to the Center for Mobile Learning with Digital Technology of the Bayreuth University.

Credits for the circle intersection function: [01AutoMonkey](https://stackoverflow.com/users/473368/01automonkey) in the accepted answer to this question: [A JavaScript function that returns the x,y points of intersection between two circles?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12221389/4845566)

```js
function deg2rad(deg) {
  return deg * Math.PI / 180;
}

function rad2deg(rad) {
  return rad * 180 / Math.PI;
}

function lessThanEpsilon(x) {
  return (Math.abs(x) < 0.00000000001);
}

function angleBetween(point1, point2) {
  var x1 = point1.X(), y1 = point1.Y(), x2 = point2.X(), y2 = point2.Y();
  var dy = y2 - y1, dx = x2 - x1;
  var t = -Math.atan2(dx, dy); /* range (PI, -PI] */
  return rad2deg(t); /* range (180, -180] */
}

function circleIntersection(circle1, circle2) {
  var r1 = circle1.radius, cx1 = circle1.center.X(), cy1 = circle1.center.Y();
  var r2 = circle2.radius, cx2 = circle2.center.X(), cy2 = circle2.center.Y();

  var a, dx, dy, d, h, h2, rx, ry, x2, y2;

  /* dx and dy are the vertical and horizontal distances between the circle centers. */
  dx = cx2 - cx1;
  dy = cy2 - cy1;
  
  /* angle between circle centers */
  var theta = Math.atan2(dy,dx);

  /* vertical and horizontal components of the line connecting the circle centers */
  var xs1 = r1*Math.cos(theta), ys1 = r1*Math.sin(theta), xs2 = r2*Math.cos(theta), ys2 = r2*Math.sin(theta);
  
  /* intersection points of the line connecting the circle centers */
  var sxA = cx1 + xs1, syA = cy1 + ys1, sxL = cx2 - xs2, syL = cy2 - ys2;
  
  /* Determine the straight-line distance between the centers. */
  d = Math.sqrt((dy*dy) + (dx*dx));

  /* Check for solvability. */
  if (d > (r1 + r2)) {
    /* no solution. circles do not intersect. */
    return [[sxA,syA], [sxL,syL]];
  }

  thetaA = -Math.PI - Math.atan2(cx1,cy1); /* Swap X-Y and re-orient to -Y */
  xA = +r1*Math.sin(thetaA);
  yA = -r1*Math.cos(thetaA);
  ixA = cx1 - xA;
  iyA = cy1 - yA;

  thetaL = Math.atan(cx2/cy2);
  xL = -r2*Math.sin(thetaL);
  yL = -r2*Math.cos(thetaL);
  ixL = cx2 - xL;
  iyL = cy2 - yL;

  if(d === 0 && r1 === r2) {
    /* infinite solutions. circles are overlapping */
    return [[ixA,iyA], [ixL,iyL]];
  }
  
  if (d < Math.abs(r1 - r2)) {
    /* no solution. one circle is contained in the other */
   return [[ixA,iyA], [ixL,iyL]];
  }

  /* 'point 2' is the point where the line through the circle intersection points crosses the line between the circle centers. */

  /* Determine the distance from point 0 to point 2. */
  a = ((r1*r1) - (r2*r2) + (d*d)) / (2.0 * d);
  
  /* Determine the coordinates of point 2. */
  x2 = cx1 + (dx * a/d);
  y2 = cy1 + (dy * a/d);
  
  /* Determine the distance from point 2 to either of the intersection points. */
  h2 = r1*r1 - a*a;
  h = lessThanEpsilon(h2) ? 0 : Math.sqrt(h2);

  /* Now determine the offsets of the intersection points from point 2. */
  rx = -dy * (h/d);
  ry = +dx * (h/d);

  /* Determine the absolute intersection points. */
  var xi = x2 + rx, yi = y2 + ry;
  var xi_prime = x2 - rx, yi_prime = y2 - ry;

  return [[xi, yi], [xi_prime, yi_prime]];
}

function plot() {

  var cases = [
    {a: 1.1, l: 1.9, f: 0.3073},
    {a: 1.0, l: 1.7, f: 0.3229}
  ];

  var testCase = 1;
  
  var magA = cases[testCase].a, magL = cases[testCase].l;
  var maxS = Math.sqrt(magA*magA+magL*magL), magS1 = maxS * cases[testCase].f, magS2 = maxS - magS1;

  var origin = [0,0], board = JXG.JSXGraph.initBoard('jxgbox', {boundingbox: [-5.0, 5.0, 5.0, -5.0], axis: true});
  var drawAs = {dashed: {dash: 3, strokeWidth: 0.5, strokeColor: '#888888'} };

  board.suspendUpdate();

  var leftArm = board.create('slider', [[-4.5, 3], [-1.5, 3], [0, -64, -180]]);
  var leftLeg = board.create('slider', [[-4.5, 2], [-1.5, 2], [0, -12, -30]]);

  var rightArm = board.create('slider', [[0.5, 3], [3.5, 3], [0, 64, 180]]);
  var rightLeg = board.create('slider', [[0.5, 2], [3.5, 2], [0, 12, 30]]);

  var lh = board.create('point', [
    function() { return +magA * Math.sin(deg2rad(leftArm.Value())); },
    function() { return -magA * Math.cos(deg2rad(leftArm.Value())); }
  ], {size: 3, name: 'lh'});
  var LA = board.create('line', [origin, lh], {straightFirst: false, straightLast: false, lastArrow: true});
  var cLS1 = board.create('circle', [function() { return [lh.X(), lh.Y()]; }, function() { return magS1; }], drawAs.dashed);
  
  var lf = board.create('point', [
    function() { return +magL * Math.sin(deg2rad(leftLeg.Value())); },
    function() { return -magL * Math.cos(deg2rad(leftLeg.Value())); }
  ], {size: 3, name: 'lf'});
  var LL = board.create('line', [origin, lf], {straightFirst: false, straightLast: false, lastArrow: true});
  var cLS2 = board.create('circle', [function() { return [lf.X(), lf.Y()]; }, function() { return magS2; }], drawAs.dashed);

  var lx1 = board.create('point', [
    function() { return circleIntersection(cLS1, cLS2)[0][0]; },
    function() { return circleIntersection(cLS1, cLS2)[0][1]; }
  ], {size: 3, face:'x', name: 'lx1'});

  var lx2 = board.create('point', [
    function() { return circleIntersection(cLS1, cLS2)[1][0]; },
    function() { return circleIntersection(cLS1, cLS2)[1][1]; }
  ], {size: 3, face:'x', name: 'lx2'});

  /* Angle between lh, lx1 shall be between 0 and -180 */
  var angleLAJ = board.create('text', [-3.7, 0.5, function(){ return angleBetween(lh, lx1).toFixed(2); }]);
  /* Angle between lf, lx1 shall be between 0 and 180 */
  var angleLLJ = board.create('text', [-2.7, 0.5, function(){ return angleBetween(lf, lx1).toFixed(2); }]);
  
  var rh = board.create('point', [
    function() { return +magA * Math.sin(deg2rad(rightArm.Value())); },
    function() { return -magA * Math.cos(deg2rad(rightArm.Value())); }
  ], {size: 3, name: 'rh'});
  var RA = board.create('line', [origin, rh], {straightFirst: false, straightLast: false, lastArrow: true});
  var cRS1 = board.create('circle', [function() { return [rh.X(), rh.Y()]; }, function() { return magS1; }], drawAs.dashed);
  
  var rf = board.create('point', [
    function() { return +magL * Math.sin(deg2rad(rightLeg.Value())); },
    function() { return -magL * Math.cos(deg2rad(rightLeg.Value())); }
  ], {size: 3, name: 'rf'});
  var RL = board.create('line', [origin, rf], {straightFirst: false, straightLast: false, lastArrow: true});
  var cRS2 = board.create('circle', [function() { return [rf.X(), rf.Y()]; }, function() { return magS2; }], drawAs.dashed);

  var rx1 = board.create('point', [
    function() { return circleIntersection(cRS1, cRS2)[1][0]; },
    function() { return circleIntersection(cRS1, cRS2)[1][1]; }
  ], {size: 3, face:'x', name: 'rx1'});

  var rx2 = board.create('point', [
    function() { return circleIntersection(cRS1, cRS2)[0][0]; },
    function() { return circleIntersection(cRS1, cRS2)[0][1]; }
  ], {size: 3, face:'x', name: 'rx2'});
  
  var angleRAJ = board.create('text', [+1.3, 0.5, function(){ return angleBetween(rh, rx1).toFixed(2); }]);
  var angleRLJ = board.create('text', [+2.3, 0.5, function(){ return angleBetween(rf, rx1).toFixed(2); }]);

  board.unsuspendUpdate();

}

plot();
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jsxgraph/0.99.7/jsxgraph.css" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
  <script type="text/javascript" charset="UTF-8" src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jsxgraph/0.99.7/jsxgraphcore.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <div id="jxgbox" class="jxgbox" style="width:580px; height:580px;"></div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: First calculate the dot product between vectors OG and OH, then the magnitude of those vectors, finally you can calculate the cosine of the new angle at origin for the upper triangle. The arccos of the given figures upper triangle is approx. 38 degrees. Now you have the new angle between OG and OH. Using the sum of angles you can get the other angle which is eg. `angle_at_H = 180-(24.62+38)=117.38 `. Using that you can get the other angle by  arithmatic. Hope it helps.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it has no relation to programming

Comment: @BjoernRennhak: sorry, I don't know where H lies, so can't compute the dot product. Could You please elaborate?

Comment: @MBo agree, seems very Mathoverflow-y.

Comment: @deblocker Can you please edit your question to clearly state what you know in your question context?

Comment: @BjoernRennhak: thanks for persuading me to add some more detail to my question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to your sketch, the coordinates of E and G are:

```
E = (0, -magOE)
G = magOG * ( -sin(gamma), -cos(gamma) )
```

Then, calculating the position of H is a [trilateration](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trilateration) problem. Actually, it is just bilateration because you are missing a third distance. Hence, you will get two possible positions for H.

First, let us define a new coordinate system, where E lies at the origin and G lies on the x-axis. The x-axis direction in our original coordinate system is then:

```
x = (G - E) / ||G - E||
```

The y-axis is:

```
y = ( x.y, -x.x )
```

The coordinates of E and G in this new coordinate system are:

```
E* = (0, 0)
G* = (0, ||G - E||)
```

Now, we can easily find the coordinates of H in this coordinate system, up to the ambiguity mentioned earlier. I will abbreviate `||G - E|| = d` like in the notation used in the Wikipedia article:

```
H.x* = (magGH * magGH - magEH * magEH + d * d) / (2 * d)
H.y* = +- sqrt(magGH * magGH - H.x* * H.x*)
```

Hence, we have two solutions for `H.y`, one positive and one negative.

Finally, we just need to transform H back into our original coordinate system:

```
H = x * H.x* + y * H.y* - (0, magOE)
```

Given the coordinates of H, calculating the angles is pretty straightforward:

```
alpha = arccos((H.x - G.x) / ||H - G||)
beta  = arccos((H.y - E.y) / ||H - E||)
```

### Example

Taking the values from your example

```
magOG = 3
magOE = 4
magGH = 3
magEH = 2
angleGamma = 82.74°
```

we first get:

```
E = (0, -4)
G = 3 * ( -sin(82.74°), -cos(82.74°) )
  = (-2.976, -0.379)
```

Our coordinate system:

x = (-0.635,  0.773)
   y = ( 0.773,  0.635)

In this coordinate system:

```
E* = (0, 0)
G* = (0, 4.687)
```

Then, the coordinates of H in our auxiliary coordinate system are:

```
H* = (2.877, +- 0.851)
```

I will only focus on the positive value for H*.y because this is the point that you marked in your sketch.

Transform back to original coordinate system:

```
H = (-1.169, -1.237)
```

And finally calculate the angles:

```
alpha = 25.41°
beta  = 22.94°
```

The slight differences to your values are probably caused by rounding errors (either in my calculations or in yours).

Comment: Your hint about the bilateration helped me a lot. After Your explanation I managed to solve this problem by using the circle intersection You mentioned.

Comment: Now, I am experiencing (as usual...) a weird JavaScript floating point issue by using `Math.sqrt` which gives me sometimes `NaN` (just for curiosity, here is an example: Math.sqrt(2.2222222222222223 - 2.2222222222222228). This is the case where both circles are nearby tangent. Are You maybe aware of some workarounds how to handle this particular situation?

Comment: BTW, the differences in result are because I accidentally inverted the values of `magGH`and `magEH` in code. Good catch, my fault ;)

Comment: If you are certain that the circles intersect, you can set `H*.y=0` if the argument of sqrt becomes negative.